# Add key/value to an object inside an array

Tags: javascript

How can i add a key+value to each object in my array. Do i have to make a loop or is there a simple method to do that?

What i have :

```js
var tab = [];

tab.push({name: 'Volvo', firstname: 'Doto'}, {name: 'Velve', firstname: 'Dete'});
```

What i need is to add a property image for each object inside the tab array.

Like this :

```js
var tab = [];

tab.push({name: 'Volvo', firstname: 'Doto', image: 'Volvoimg'}, {name: 'Velve', firstname: 'Dete', image: 'Velveimg'});
```

Comment: iterate the array and add the property to each of the objects.

Comment: Something like this : $.each(tab, function(i, field){ field.img = myimage; } ? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map is one way if you wish to return an new array. [gurvinder372 has an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35918965/add-key-value-to-an-object-inside-an-array/35919149#35919014) that shows how to use map.

An alternative is to use a forEach, this however has whats called 'side effects' and probably isn't the best approach. I think the map example is best, but I've included this as a matter of completeness.

```
tab.forEach((obj) => obj.image = "whatever goes here");
```

Comment: I never used map() before i'll look for it, thanks for your answer this is what i needed even if i knew it was something like this

Comment: I'd encourage you to research map, even if you don't use it in this example it's still a very powerful function and does solve many problems. Also If you're done with this question please do mark it as answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

try

```
tab = tab.map( function(value){value.image  = value.name + "img"; return value;} )
```

Comment: Well i think it was a bad example, i'm not trying to add the word "img" to the value, just to add a loop of image to my tab array for each obj

Comment: @teddym can you share the example of what you are looking for? Since my answer seems to be in synch with your question.

Comment: Well i never used map before, i'm reading the doc, i found the solution but thanks man, we learn everyday